# Finding unreferenced documents

Tags: javascript, performance, mongodb

I have a database containing at least 2 collections `datagroup` and `data`.
Each `data` document have a reference to the `_id` of one of the `datagroup` documents.

I want to find all `datagroup` documents that have no `data` pointing to, the fastest as possible.

For this, I use a **javascript mongo shell script**.

I have these options for now (if you have one more, feel free to suggest):

> Notes:
>
> - `data.vid` is the same value as `datagroup._id` (like external key, of kind `ObjectId`)
> - There is a large number of `data` (~`100,000,000`) and `datagroup` (~`20,000`)

**Option 1:** (123s)

```
/* 0s since beginning (experimented) */
// get id of all datagroups used in data
let withData = db.data.find({})           // get all data
                      .map(d=>d.vid)      // to array of ObjectId
/* 1m40s since beginning (experimented) */

withData = Array.from(new Set(withData)); // remove duplicates in array
/* 1m52s since beginning (experimented) */

// find datagroup that ids not in ObjectId array
let withoutData = db.datagroup.find({_id: {$nin: withData}})
                              .map(dg=>dg._id);  // get their ids
/* 2m03s since beginning (experimented) */
```

**Option 2:** (59s)

```
/* 0s since beginning (experimented) */
// get id of all datagroups used in data
let withData = db.data.aggregate([
    {$project:{vid:1, _id:0}},       // keep only references to datagroups
    {$group:{_id:"$vid"}}            // remove duplicates
]).map(d=>d.vid.str);                // to array of ObjectId strings
/* 37s since beginning (experimented) */

let withoutData = db.datagroup.find({})      // find all datagroups
                              .map(dg=>dg._id) // get theys ids
                                             // compare with array of ids
                              .filter(vid => withData.indexOf(vid.str) < 0);
/* 59s since beginning (experimented) */
```

**Option 3:** (109s)

```
/* 0s since beginning (experimented) */
let withoutData = db.datagroup.aggregate([
    {$project:{_id:1}},       // keep only ids
    {$lookup:{
        from: "data",         // grouping data with datagroups
        localField: "_id",
        foreignField: "vid",
        as: "dgs"
    }},
    {$match:{dgs:[]}}        // keep only datagroups without data
]).map(dg=>dg._id);
/* 1ms49 since beginning (experimented) */
```

Do you think there is a better way than doing this, or should I use the option 2 because it's just the best way to do this kind of request ? (Or maybe you have ideas in order to speed up my options ?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a better way, but this assume that you have an index on **vid** field (for example, `{"vid": 1}` ). If you don't, you can create one using `db.data.ensureIndex({"vid": 1})`. This can take several minutes to end.

The fastest solution (option 2) use **`$group`** after a **`$project`**  Here the `$project` stage only add overhead and does not speed up the `$group` stage, so we can get rid of it.

Currently, the **`$group`** operator can't take advantage of index, so it can be quite slow for such big dataset. A better solution would be to use [`distinct()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/) instead

> **Index Use**
>
> When possible, db.collection.distinct() operations can use indexes.

so we can fetch `withData` array simply using this:

```
let withData = db.data.distinct("vid")
```

Then, the datagroup collection is filtered using `map()` and `filter()`. On really big array, this can be really expensive as javascript is quite slow. Instead, we can let mongodb do this operation with a simple query using [**`$nin`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/):

```
let withoutData = db.datagroup.distinct("_id", {"_id": {$nin: withData}})
```

As `distinct()` returns an array, we get directly the result in proper format, so we can avoid js mapping and filtering.

so the final script is:

```
let withData = db.data.distinct("vid")
let withoutData = db.datagroup.distinct("_id", {"_id": {$nin: withData}})
```

---

### Some results

on my machine (ubuntu16.04) , with a similar dataset ( 100 000 000 docs in data, 20000 in datagroup)

New script runs in less than 5s :

```
time mongo test < newOption.js
0,06s user 0,00s system 1% cpu 3,534 total
```

Comment: Wow !! Very interesting ! It was somethng like this `distinct` operator I wanted to find. 1: Yes there is an index on vid, so this will work; 2: Took 4s for me (just one try), perfect; Thank you @felix